# Notification for Smooth scrolling completion in listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have one listview and there is one button. onClickListner() of this button adds one more element on the top of the list.

**Problem:**

- first list view should autoscroll to that added element (means
  top as new element is getting added on top only)
- then click should be performed to that newly added element in listview.

**What Have I Tried:**

I have tried to add a post delay runnable on listview queue but that is not much helping because sometimes list is scrolling and click performs.
also when you are already at top of the list then one delay appears till the click would be performed. (Delay is fixed 800Ms). Element in list can go upto 500.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    openProject(0,true);
                }
            }, 600);
           ...
     }
```

**Is there any other way to make it more user friendly and much more appealing?**

Comment: can you please share your code here??

Comment: where you adding data in array? can you please share your code inside openProject method.

Comment: that's before smoothscrolling call. it is just adding the data in the array and adaptor is working on that. can you tell me if you have any approach in your mind?

Comment: can you please change your order like:  
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);